# Why is a delegated method public when declared in a private section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates, metaprogramming

I can make `attr_reader` (and the related `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor`) method(s) private by putting the declaration in a `private` section:

```
class Foo
private
  attr_reader :b
end

Foo.new.b # => NoMethodError: private method `b' called for #<Foo:>
```

However, Rails' [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Module/delegate) and the Ruby standard library's [`def_delegate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html#method-i-def_delegator) do not work this way. These delegated methods are always public.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :b
  def initialize
    @b = 'b'
  end
end

require 'forwardable'
class Bar
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize
    @foo = Foo.new
  end
  extend Forwardable
private
  def_delegator :foo, :b
end

Bar.new.b # => "b"
```

Making the delegation private is easily done by changing it to:

```
private def_delegator :foo, :b
```

but I expected a `NoMethodError` error for `Bar.new.b` above. Why isn't the delegation private?

The method definition of `def_delegator` (alias for `def_instance_delegator`) is just `rescue` (blocks removed):

```
def def_instance_delegator(accessor, method, ali = method)
  line_no = __LINE__; str = %Q{
    def #{ali}(*args, &block)
      #{accessor}.__send__(:#{method}, *args, &block)
    end
  }
  module_eval(str, __FILE__, line_no)
end
```

That means `module_eval` does not respect that it was called in a `private` section. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with `module_eval` because it explicitly sets public visibility before evaling passed string.
It behaves in the same way in CRuby and JRuby. For example, incriminated code for CRuby is in [eval_under](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_eval.c#1534) function.

As you've figured out, when you pass `def_delegate` to `private` method it becomes private. `def_delegate` first defines passed method as public (by the underlying module_eval), then is *reset* by `private` to private visibility.

It's not 100% clear if current `Module.module_eval`'s behavior is correct one or there is a bug in `Forwardable.def_instance_delegator`. `module_eval` examples in documentation guide to use it outside concerned class/module and it does not expect visibility argument so it seems logical it sets method's visibility to public.

The solution would be either `Module.module_eval` handle optional visibility argument *and* respect current visibility when sent to implicit or explicit `self` (doubt if possible) or fix `Forwardable.def_instance_delegator` implementation to define method with more appropriate `Module.define_method` instead of `module_eval`.
In any case this is a good candidate for filling a bug report on http://bugs.ruby-lang.org .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as it is supposed to work. I always consider that visibility modifiers are affecting the scope they are written in and not any calls originating from there. In this sense the call to module_eval does not know that it is inside a private section (could it?).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the second option works while the first doesn't because Rails is saying "module_eval this specific line". So, when you have private on the same line it understands that it should begin treating it as a private method definition. This seems like something that should be fixed by the Rails maintainers, create an issue for them.